# I'm trying to download VS Code on linux and it's giving me this problem (first time ever on Linux)

Tags: linux, visual-studio-code, download

Note, selecting 'code:amd64' instead of './code_1.82.0-1694039253_amd64.deb'
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.

I tried sudo apt --fix-broken install and no luck I have no clue

Answer (score 0):

## The easier one.

Try running `uname -m` or `arch`. If the output is `x86_64`, you have the right platform, and you should try my second suggestion. If it is something like `arm32` or `arm64`, download the corresponding deb from from the [downloads page](https://code.visualstudio.com/download).

## The automated script

Save this script in your `~/Downloads` folder as `install_vscode.sh`

```bash
sudo apt-get install wget gpg apt-transport-https
wget -qO- https://packages.microsoft.com/keys/microsoft.asc | gpg --dearmor > packages.microsoft.gpg
sudo install -D -o root -g root -m 644 packages.microsoft.gpg /etc/apt/keyrings/packages.microsoft.gpg
sudo sh -c 'echo "deb [arch=amd64,arm64,armhf signed-by=/etc/apt/keyrings/packages.microsoft.gpg] https://packages.microsoft.com/repos/code stable main" > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/vscode.list'
rm -f packages.microsoft.gpg
sudo apt update
sudo apt install code # or code-insiders
```

Then run the following commands in the terminal:

```bash
cd ~/Downloads
chmod +x ./install_vscode.sh
sh ./install_vscode.sh
```

it should work.

**Edit**: If you have snap store installed, search code (or code-insiders) in the gui and install, or the following command in the terminal: `sudo snap install --classic code # or code-insiders`

Comment: Your welcome. It's always nice to see that I helped someone else.